# Disable the Volume Toast

Tags: android, volume

I'm trying to increase the volume using AudioManager.

But it showing Native Android Volume UI(Volume Seekbar) toast.I want to disable this.
I know this can be possible in Activity using Key Event but i want to do it through service.
How to disable the toast?
Here is a screenshot of the toast:
[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of this "Toast".

Comment: When you increase or decrease a volume,it will volume Seekbar natively.I want to disable this.

Answer (score 10):

The `AudioManager`-class offers the following methods to adjust the volume of certain streams:

- [`adjustVolume(int, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustVolume%28int,%20int%29)
- [`adjustStreamVolume(int, int, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29)
- [`adjustSuggestedStreamVolume(int, int, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustSuggestedStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29)
- [`setStreamVolume(int, int, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

All those methods take a `flag`-parameter as their last argument. The flag which is interesting for you is the [`FLAG_SHOW_UI`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#FLAG_SHOW_UI) which:

> Show a toast containing the current volume.

So, to get rid of the Toast, **don't** supply this flag (or the int-value 1) but supply all your other flags (if needed) or just `0`:

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
manager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, 0);
```

The above code-snippet works for me on Android 4.0.4 (Motorola Xoom) and Android 2.3.5 (HTC Desire HD).

Comment: @SatheeshKumar I tested it on my devices and added a code-snippet that worked for me. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Lukas Knuth Your code snippet is incomplete to me at least. Where do you add this code? In the OnKeyDown listener?

Comment: @Radu you put it wherever you need the volume to be increased. The last line increases the volume, you can put that into your `KeyListener`.

Comment: Can't get this to work, did you? On my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 the toast still shows even when the FLAG is set to 0.

Comment: @JonPM as mentioned, it worked for me. On the other hand, you're taking control from the user, so it makes sense to force the toast.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a little bit late, but I think I've managed to hide the volume toast using this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch(keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            //volumeDown();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            //volumeUp();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch(keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            volumeDown();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            volumeUp();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private void volumeUp(){
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SOME_RANDOM_VALUE, AudioManager.FLAG_VIBRATE);
}
```

Ovveriding only one method from onKeyUp and onKeyDown didn't prevent displaying the toast (even when using flags).

It's a little bit weird - like Android tries to display the toast twice.