# Android Audio manager and volume screen

Tags: android, audio

When you push the volume up or down key on the side of your phone, a volume notification pops up on the screen notifying you of the volume change. What is like to know is, could you make an app that replaces that notifying screen? Without making your app just appear over it?

Comment: See here for the same problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163933/disable-the-volume-toast